How to correctly extract data from .ve file in Linux
I've got some files, from a vmware mnt partition, that end in .tgz.ve My problem is that I can't extract the data from them. When I run the file command on it file myfile.tgz.ve, all I get for the content type is data
What I'd like is a tool to extract the data, or at the very least, an explanation on what the file extension is and what it's used for.
